# The structure of "he works as an architect"

Tags: grammar

I am aware that the basic grammar pattern of a sentence is `subject + predicate + object`, where *object* is optional.

In this sentence,

> I want a cup of tea

"I" is a personal pronoun, which functions as a subject; "want" is a verb, which functions as a  predicate; "a cup of tea" is a noun phrase, which functions as an object.

So far so good.

Consider another sentence,

> He works as an architect.

"He" is a personal pronoun, which functions as a subject; "want" is a verb, which functions as a  predicate.

How about the last part? Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

**Note**: I understand the sentence conveys someone's occupation, what does he do for a living, and that is NOT what I am asking. I am asking about its grammatical function and analysis.

Similar to "subject", "predicate", what is the t**erm (or canonical name)** to describe the component of a sentence that "as an architect" functions as? Obviously, it is not an "object".

Comment: 'To work _as_ a [whatever]' is a standard way of stating someone's occupation. That's all.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you. I understand the sentence conveys someone's occupation, what does he do for a living, and that is NOT what I am asking. I am asking about its grammatical function and analysis.

Comment: I meant that this is simply one of the uses of **as**. Cambridge English Dictionary says: ' used to describe the purpose or quality of someone or something: 
_She works as a waitress.
It could be used as evidence against him_.'

Comment: @KateBunting I guess I didn't clarify my question. Let's try it again :) Similar to "subject", "predicate", what is the term (or canonical name) to describe the component of a sentence that "as an architect" functions as, obviously, it is not an "object".

Comment: An adverbial phrase modifying 'works'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, **as** is a preposition and **an architect** is the object of the preposition.

> **He** is a subject pronoun
>   **works** is an intransitive verb
>  
>   **as an architect** is a [prepositional phrase](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/prepositional-phrase/) which modifies the verb **works**.

Note that **prepositional phrase** describes how it was constructed - it starts with a preposition. We can also describe it in terms of its grammatical function within the sentence. A prepositional phrase can function as an [adverbial phrase](http://grammar-monster.com/glossary/adverbial_phrases.htm) when it modifies a verb, or as an adjectival phrase when it modifies a noun, for example

> The man **at the centre of the controversy** is ..."

In your example, it modifies a verb, so it is functioning as an adverbial phrase.

Comment: Thank you. Similar to "subject",  "predicate",  what is the term (or canonical name) to describe the component of a sentence that "as an architect" functions as, obviously, it is not an "object".

Comment: @WXJ96163 I have added some more information to my answer.